# Conversion from assembly program to low-level machine language

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, machine-code

While studying COMPILER-DESIGN through an online book from Google-Books,referenced as [`Compiler Design
 By A.A.Puntambekar`](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=igpL2CqjapYC&pg=SA1-PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false), I got stuck across a line. Actually, I am more curious to know the inner-detail.

> The assembler converts the assembly-program to low-level machine
>   language using two passes. A pass means one complete scan of the input
>   program. The end of the second pass is the relocatable machine code.

Why the 2 passes for conversion and what are the phases involved like lexical analysis,syntax analysis,etc while conversion from assembly to machine-code??? I have very less/no idea about it.

If someone over here would like to describe those two-passes or link out to some good resources, I'd be thankful to him/her

Comment: This is not really a programming question. It's asking about how computers work. Maybe http://cs.stackexchange.com would be a better fit. (Also, not all assemblers are two-pass assemblers.)

Comment: I guess programmers of assembly and machine-code are more likely to be available here rather than on that website. But,I'll post on that too. Any help about the question? @RaymondChen

Comment: @RaymondChen-Asking about code conversion,not computer's working!

Comment: You are also more likely to find doctors at the golf course, but that doesn't mean it's okay to go to the golf course and ask people for medical advice.

Comment: You are asking how assemblers work, which is off topic for this site. (Conceptual / too broad.) If you have a specific programming problem, like a program that is not working properly, you can post that question here.

Comment: Try to find out how [Low Level Virtual Machine (LLVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) works internally, what are the stages etc. As this is an example of universal "assembler"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has to replace labels by their offsets. If you use the name of a label in a earlier line than the label itself, the compiler will have to repass the program for inserting the offset.

Comment: Ok,means all the labels are replaced by actual memory-mappings(registers),then in the second pass,code conversion is done?

Comment: Also, depending on the size of the code between a label and a jump, the jump may require different encoding. Some jumps are "long jumps" others may be optimized to be "short jumps" (well at least in some assemblers).

Comment: Thanks @vanUitkon. It helped in clearing basic concept.